# What type of variable does Serial.print() use?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

On arduino, I need to use Serial.print() inside a function like;

```
void loop()
{
    serial_send(any_type);
}

void serial_send(type message)
{
   Serial.print(message);
}
```

`Serial.print` can accept any type of variable such as `int`, `double` or `String`. How can I get that same behavior with `serial_send` so I do not have to specify a type?

Comment: Why not google "Serial.pring arduino" and click on [one of the first results](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/) to find out?

Comment: @TomášZato I think the point of the question here is to understand how it's *possible* that a function like `Serial.print()` can accept any type of argument — I'd imagine that the OP might like to write his/her own functions that can take any type. This is a good question. The answer could be found in the source code, but the OP may not know where to find that.

Comment: @Caleb Apologies, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what templates are for.  Using

```
template <typename T>
void serial_send(T message)
{
   Serial.print(message);
}
```

you can call `serial_send` with any type you want and as longs as `print` has an overload for it it will work.  If not you'll get an error for no matching call to `print`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not one `Serial.print`. Function name `print` is 'overloaded' for many functions with different parameters. Excerpt from [Print.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.h)

```
    size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *);
    size_t print(const String &);
    size_t print(const char[]);
    size_t print(char);
    size_t print(unsigned char, int = DEC);
    size_t print(int, int = DEC);
    size_t print(unsigned int, int = DEC);
    size_t print(long, int = DEC);
    size_t print(unsigned long, int = DEC);
    size_t print(double, int = 2);
    size_t print(const Printable&);
```

If you want to wrap Serial.print functions, you can use a template function from NathanOliver's answer. The compiler will generate a function based on the template for every parameter type used in your sketch with the template.